# SQL UNPIVOT assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016

I have a query which returns a large amount of columns from two tables; one which has orders from the beginning of the week and one from today. I am then comparing the weekly orders to the daily orders to see if there are any differences.

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE
      WHEN w.[DueDate] != d.[DueDate]
        THEN 'Due Date'
      WHEN w.[ItemCode] != d.[ItemCode]
        THEN 'ItemCode'
      WHEN w.[PlannedQty] != d.[PlannedQty]
        THEN 'Planned Qty'
    END [Discrepancy] 
FROM
   (SELECT 
        'Daily' [Period],
        *
    FROM
        DailyProduction) d
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
           'Weekly' [Period],
           *
         FROM
           WeeklyProduction) w ON w.[DocNum] = d.[DocNum]
```

Which returns something like:

[image]

Which is great.

However I would like to separate the *Daily* from the *Weekly* results by having them in a separate row, while also then maintaining the *Discrepancy* column for both new rows.

Like this
[image]

I think that I need to use `UNPIVOT` but I've been reading related questions / blogs for the past 2+ hours and can't figure out how it works.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: How did you even get that format in first query? Shouldn't SQL Server complain about duplicate column name?

Comment: I simplified it a bit, the daily columns all have a "d" before them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run a `UNION` query, selecting fields only from specific table in `FROM/JOIN` clauses:

```
SELECT
   'Daily' AS [Period],
    d.Status, d.DocNum, d.ProductionDate, d.DueDate, d.Week, 
    d.DueDay, d.ItemCode, d.PlannedQty,
    CASE
      WHEN w.[DueDate] != d.[DueDate]
        THEN 'Due Date'
      WHEN w.[ItemCode] != d.[ItemCode]
        THEN 'ItemCode'
      WHEN w.[PlannedQty] != d.[PlannedQty]
        THEN 'Planned Qty'
    END [Discrepancy] 
FROM
   DailyProduction d
LEFT JOIN
   WeeklyProduction w ON w.[DocNum] = d.[DocNum]

UNION ALL

SELECT
   'Weekly' AS [Period],
    w.Status, w.DocNum, w.ProductionDate, w.DueDate, w.Week, 
    w.DueDay, w.ItemCode, w.PlannedQty,
    CASE
      WHEN w.[DueDate] != d.[DueDate]
        THEN 'Due Date'
      WHEN w.[ItemCode] != d.[ItemCode]
        THEN 'ItemCode'
      WHEN w.[PlannedQty] != d.[PlannedQty]
        THEN 'Planned Qty'
    END [Discrepancy] 
FROM
   DailyProduction d
LEFT JOIN
   WeeklyProduction w ON w.[DocNum] = d.[DocNum]
```

Comment: So easy! Thanks so much.